# Android Activity with FragmentTabHost - going back from details calls "onCreate" in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, oncreate, onrestoreinstancestate

I am facing some strange behaviour on a Samsung Alpha (4.4.4). I have built an App with a `MainActivity` that has a FragmentTabHost with 4 different `Fragments` (Tabs). On each of these tabs you can search for different things, and when tap on one of them a new activity is being called and the details are being shown.

Now, when running the App on my Samsung S3 (4.2) and the emulator (4.4, Samsung S5) everything works fine, that means, when I click on the details and go back to my `MainActivity` I can still see my list entries (and all the other fragments are presistent in their state). Now, when I run my app on my gilfriends phone, Samsung Alpha 4.4.4, every time I turn back from the details activity `onCreate` is being called in my `**MainActivity**` and that of course means that all my fragments are being created again (so they are empty). How is it possible that the phones behave different and what can I do to to save my data ? I know that I can save my list entries and the restore them (and then I would have to restore all my fragments every time somebody clicks on the details), but I think, since it is working on my phone, maybe it is a flag or something I have to set.
This is how I have been restoring my lists after navigating back to my activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        registerForContextMenu(getView());

        if (mPersonList == null)
            mPersonList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        mListView = (SwipeListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.liste_personen);


        if (mPersonAdapter != null)
            mPersonAdapter = new ArrayAdapterPerson(getActivity(), R.layout.zelle_person, mPersonList,mPersonAdapter.getGefilterteListe());
        else
            mPersonAdapter = new ArrayAdapterPerson(getActivity(), R.layout.zelle_person, mPersonList,mPersonList);

        mListView.setAdapter(mPersonAdapter);
}
```

But since the activity, and so the fragment, is being newly created `mPersonList` is always `null`

Comment: Developer options -> apps --> Don't keep activities. Is this selection true?

Comment: Thank you very much :). Actually I had a brief look at the developer options on her phone but I didnt find it. Now after looking closely I found it under the menu "Menu" (her phone is on german).A bit confusing, but you got it. Thanks again